# Compare two API versions for changes in class/function names

Tags: python, diff, abstract-syntax-tree

Lets say there is some python module:

```
version = "1.0"
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self, x):
        pass
    def bar(self, y):
        pass
```

in a later version some of the functions are changed:

```
version = "2.0"
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self, x, y):
        pass
    def baz(self):
        pass
```

I would like to create a diff of those two modules resulting in such an output:

```
-Bar.bar
~Bar.foo has changed signature
+Bar.baz
```

I know [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) but before I reinvent the wheel and write everything from scratch: Is there a tool that can create such diffs (the exact format is not required!)? I could not find any but I fear I'm just searching with the wrong terms...

Comment: There is a tool called [GumTreeDiff](https://github.com/GumTreeDiff/gumtree/issues/31) but the python support is not yet available. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: this looks good - or any other tool that can create an AST which can be compared using the usual diff tools